# How to suspend website for users but left it activated for the developer?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, plesk

I would like to set a page on my website "Coming soon",and open the website when the update is finished.
My website is on host with plesk panel, so I suspended my site and edited the "temporary unavialable service" error page. but now as the developer i cannot check my website( I have to check it on the host and not in the IDE).
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) you could do a few different things, here are a few of the easier ones:

1. Redirect by IP. Send everyone that doesn't match your IP address to a maintenance page (make sure you use a 302). If you're on a network where everyone has the same external IP and users on that network are accessing the site, this could be an issue.
2. Redirect by (lack of) a querystring parameter. This will work if you just need to view and refresh a single page, but if you need to click around through the site it's not going to work.
3. Redirect by (lack of) a cookie. Have Url Rewrite look for a cookie and if it's not present, redirect to maintenance page. This is probably the best solution of the 3 as it avoids the pitfalls of the other two approaches. The cookie will persist for however long you tell it to so you won't get redirected when you click through as you would with the querystring approach, and the redirects will work for everyone that doesn't have a cookie set- so everybody but you.

There are plenty of examples of all of these approaches on this site and on [Webmasters.StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) and all over the web that can be found with quick search.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is leave your site up with the home page one of the static pages of your asp.net website and have your page for the site that you are working on called something like home2.aspx. I'm that way people that go to your site without a specific page will get the under construction page and you just need to add the URL of your test page when you deploy